# How to write mp4 metadata with ffmpeg without affecting the video data

Tags: video, ffmpeg, metadata, mp4

I'm trying to write metadata to a video file in one step, and capture the "raw data" (no metadata) portion of a video file in another step.  The trouble is, with MP4 files, adding metadata to the file appears to alter the raw video data as well, while MKV files act as expected.  Here's an example with two files: `test.mkv` and `test.mp4`:

#### MKV

```
ffmpeg -i test.mkv -loglevel error -metadata 'arbitrary=string' -codec copy test-new-metadata.mkv

ffmpeg -i test.mkv              -loglevel error -map 0:v:0 -c copy -f data - -map 0:a:0 -c copy -f data - | md5sum
631becf821dca89b150120d25393491a  -

ffmpeg -i test-new-metadata.mkv -loglevel error -map 0:v:0 -c copy -f data - -map 0:a:0 -c copy -f data - | md5sum
631becf821dca89b150120d25393491a  -
```

#### MP4

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -loglevel error -metadata 'arbitrary=string' -codec copy test-new-metadata.mp4

ffmpeg -i test.mp4              -loglevel error -map 0:v:0 -c copy -f data - -map 0:a:0 -c copy -f data - | md5sum
b9b28e4ac500be961bd07290a34cf93f  -

ffmpeg -i test-new-metadata.mp4 -loglevel error -map 0:v:0 -c copy -f data - -map 0:a:0 -c copy -f data - | md5sum
d13e7177fae9b341994bc1ee8f3812bc  -
```

...and now webm, just to see if I'm losing my mind:

#### Webm

```
ffmpeg -i test.webm -loglevel error -metadata 'arbitrary=string' -codec copy test-new-metadata.webm

ffmpeg -i test.webm              -loglevel error -map 0:v:0 -c copy -f data - -map 0:a:0 -c copy -f data - | md5sum
a62e053d3dbf627db4d77c5165152a81  -

ffmpeg -i test-new-metadata.webm -loglevel error -map 0:v:0 -c copy -f data - -map 0:a:0 -c copy -f data - | md5sum
a62e053d3dbf627db4d77c5165152a81  -
```

So I'm left wondering if my understanding of how to capture the raw video is misinformed, or if MP4 is "special" in some way.  Note that I'm not interested in using ffmpeg's own hashing functions as I want to run the raw data through an external process.  The use of `md5sum` here is just to test if the output is identical.

**Update**: As requested, I'm including the output of the metadata writing step for MP4 files:

```
$ ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -metadata 'arbitrary=string' -codec copy test-new-metadata.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.1.1 (GCC) 20180531
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdrm --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-shared --enable-version3
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2010-03-20T21:29:11.000000Z
    encoder         : HandBrake 0.9.4 2009112300
  Duration: 00:00:05.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 551 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 560x320, 465 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-03-20T21:29:11.000000Z
      encoder         : JVT/AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 83 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-03-20T21:29:11.000000Z
Output #0, mp4, to 'test-new-metadata.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    arbitrary       : string
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 560x320, q=2-31, 465 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-03-20T21:29:11.000000Z
      encoder         : JVT/AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 83 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-03-20T21:29:11.000000Z
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  166 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     377kB time=00:00:05.54 bitrate= 556.7kbits/s speed=4.07e+03x    
video:315kB audio:56kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.609490%
```

*Update 2*: Here's a [link to the misbehaving mp4 file](https://danielquinn.org/scratch/test.mp4) (375k).

Comment: Can't reproduce here. Share full log for MP4 metadata writing cmd

Comment: Thanks for your interest.  I've just updated the question with the full output.

Comment: See nothing obvious. Test hash of just one stream at a time

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: I think I have found a clue.  If I run this: `for f in test.mp4 test-new-metadata.mp4 ; do ffmpeg -i ${f} -loglevel error -map 0:a:0 -c copy -f data - | md5sum; ffmpeg -i ${f} -loglevel error -map 0:v:0 -c copy -f data - | md5sum; done` The two streams appear to be identical.  Is it possible that my sample file has multiple audio and/or video streams in it?  How can I find out?  I've added a link to the file we're talking about in the question.

Comment: No of streams does not matter since you're only exporting the first video and audio. It only happens for the first remux. Remuxing the resulting MP4 to another MP4 and then doing a compare shows no difference.

Comment: The diff is just one character